# Different responsive layout handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the responsive layout of a site I am working on.

**Senario:** The site has 3 different layouts for Desktop, Tablet and mobile. The have pretty much same components (with some CSS adjustments) which can easily be handled by Media Query.
The requirement of my client is that the site has to be responsive and should adjust on resize of browser.

**Problem:**  The problem is that the some divs shift places in different layouts. Let's say Div1 has subdiv1, subdiv2 nad subdiv3. In some cases some other div say Div2 will have some subdivs and subdiv2 of Div1 has to show up between the subdivs of Div2. The layouts' component positions differ on parent levels and that's causing us a lot of problem reguarding how to handle it.

**Solutions we are considering**:

1. Create different themes based on user events: This solution is not viable because the themes would not themselves be responsive or even if they are responsive would not take the layout approved by the clients.
2. Use jquery to shifts the components to different parents on load and resize: This might slow down our site and might have other problems.
3. Hide show different instances of same component with CSS: This solution pretty much sounds bad.

Is there any other good solution we are overlooking, a better approach to do this? Even among any of these approaches we are wondering which one would be the best solution?

We are considering many factors such as Performance, SEO, load time etc.

I am really confused and would really appreciate some suggestion.

Comment: I would prefer jquery.

Comment: Ask yourselves and your client how frequently people actually resize their browser?  On Mobile and Tabs it can't even be done (AFAIK).  And on desktop, it's usually a difference between starting up and maximising, which is quite frequently negligible.  Of course that means the site shouldn't slow down much with using a jQuery fix, but  it's seldom worth the effort.  Being responsive isn't the same as responding to browser resize events.  Working on various initial sizes is usually enough.

Comment: If the layouts differ a lot and you need all of them to be responsive, then each of the 3 layouts must be made responsive separately, you cannot rely much on it being done automatically. I.e. start with a layout and add responsive markup as "progressive enhancement" to make it behave properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a theme for each layout and then switching themes according to User Agents. It is working alright for now, was a bit of extra work but its alright.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest dreameweaver cs6 fluid grid layout for this kind of issue. Its really great with live editing and previews of different layout mode.
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-dreamweaver-cs6/using-fluid-grid-layouts/

Comment: my problem is that the elements move inside different parent divs as the layout changes from desktop to tablet to mobile. Adjusting the fluid responsive layout was never the problem if the elements stayed inside the same div and not change position so drastically. Thanks!